# How can I reload an iframe from an angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

this is mi code :/ I tried with viewchild, with contentWindow.location.reload(true) without getting results

.HTML

```
<iframe [src]="url_safe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

.TS

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

  this.url = `${SettingsService.lemu_base}/components/contactos/#/contactos/${this.id_company}/${this.token}/${this.role}`
  this.url_safe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);

  this.change.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh iframe url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830406/how-to-refresh-iframe-url)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iframe src property as a URL dynamically Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496420/iframe-src-property-as-a-url-dynamically-angular2)